# Websocket in AWS ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat & Spring not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Tomcat in AWS EB. I have developed an application using Spring boot with tech stack Spring 4 and Java 8. My application uses Spring WebSocket to send a notification to the user. Below is the javascript entries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js" ></script>

// Create and init the SockJS object
var socket = new SockJS('/partnervestcrm/message');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
// Subscribe the '/notify' channell
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
  stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notify', function(notification) {
    // Call the notify function when receive a notification
    //notify(JSON.parse(notification.body).message);
    notify(JSON.parse(notification.body));
  });


}, function(error) {
    alert("STOMP error " + error);
});
```

This is working fine in my local when deployed to AWS EB I am getting below error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxx/notification/298/plu4ia32/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
WrappedWebSocket @ VM152:164
e.exports @ websocket.js:6
r @ websocket.js:32
r._connect @ main.js:219
r._receiveInfo @ main.js:193
n @ emitter.js:30
r.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-receiver.js:67
n @ emitter.js:30
r.emit @ emitter.js:50
(anonymous) @ info-ajax.js:37
n @ emitter.js:30
r.emit @ emitter.js:50
xhr.onreadystatechange @ abstract-xhr.js:124
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding inbound rules for security groups solved this problem. Please add the rule in ec2 dashboard > NETWORK & SECURITY (in the left pane) > security groups > inbound

[image]